# Get country a user is from based on their ip address

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one table (ipcountry) has the following columns:

```
low, high, country
```

Where if an ip address is between low and high, it belongs to country

The other table (logs) is defined as follows:

```
username, ipaddr
```

The logs table is around 100 MB.  I want to efficiently find what country a user is in based on their ip address.  I tried using the following query:

```
select distinct username from `logs` 
left join `ipcountry` on `logs`.ipaddr between `ipcountry`.low and `ipcountry`.high
where `logs`.ipaddr='<my ipaddress goes here>'
```

However, it takes way too long to execute (I killed it after a minute).  I'm wondering, is there a better way to do this?

EXPLAIN SELECT results:

[image]

EDIT:What I am looking to do is get all usernames associated with ipaddr, and beside each row show the country each username is from (which will all be the same country)

Comment: Do an `EXPLAIN SELECT...` and post the results.

Comment: Why do you want to make an overhead for yourself? You could use Google's Google Analytics! As for the SQL, its a good question!

Comment: Please phrase your question more reasonably.  '127.0.0.1' isn't going to have a country associated with it.  Are you just looking for one ipaddress?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry about that, I actually used my real ip address, but replaced it with 127.0.0.1 at the last moment for this question... I'll update my question

Comment: Why both `where logs.ipaddr='<my ipaddress goes here>'` *and* `distinct`? And what indexes you have on the tables?

Comment: @MajidFouladpour The same IP address can have many usernames, with multiple entries of the same username.  Also, I didn't include the index here becasue I didnt think it was important, but it has the index num for table logs only

Comment: You state *I want to efficiently find what country a user is in based on their ip address*. Whereas you seem to want countries for *every* ip in the logs table. That is a LOT of work. What you could do is get the country at the time the log entry gets added in and have it in a third column in that table.

Comment: No I just want a country for the given IP address listed above @MajidFouladpour aka one at a time <my ipaddress goes here>

Comment: I think you should try an index on both `low` and `high`.

Answer (score 0):

Please put multi column index on username and ipaddr, it will optimize the query.